# Почему браузер обрезает страницы

Tags: html, css, html5

[image]

Я тестирую как моя страница будет выглядеть на смартфоне и вижу такую картину

[image]

еще появляется горизонтальный скролл, хотя все блоки подогнаны под width:100%?

Comment: Добавьте код или ссылку на сайт.

Comment: Если горизонтальный скролл, который не предполагался, появляется, добавьте в стиль блока `overflow-x: hidden;`. Может, повезёт и всё станет таким, каким должно быть. А об этих отступах, скорее всего, написано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13128048)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что проблема решается с помощью правильного viewport, хотя слишком мало данных для того, чтобы говорить это с уверенностью.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```